# Controlling Tab Names in Vim

Tags: vim

In MacVim, the names of tab appears to be set to the name of the buffer most recently opened in that tab.  This makes for confusion when using splits.  How can I fix the tabnames to the top-left window in a tab?

Comment: Some of my previous entries were bunk, but now I've got it ;-)

Comment: @Sean, are you sure? Isn't it the focused window instead?

Comment: @romainl Sorry, you're correct-- it is the focused window.  The question of how to fix the tabname to a particular window remains though.

Comment: I think you've got it covered, now, thanks to Conner and pb2q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function returns the name of the buffer loaded in the top-left window:

```
function! GuiTabLabel()
    return bufname(winbufnr(1))
endfunction
```

Since you've mentioned MacVim, you can use `guitablabel`, setting it to the function that we've defined:

```
set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
```

A problem with the function above is that - depending on the working directory - it will set the tab name to the full path of the file in the top-left buffer, which can get pretty long.

Change the function to use only the filename, discarding the path:

```
function! GuiTabLabel()
    return fnamemodify(bufname(winbufnr(1)), ":t")
endfunction
```

To persist this, define the function in your .vimrc, and after the function:

```
set guitablabel=%!GuiTabLabel()
```

But the simple set isn't working for me using MacVim: it looks like MacVim startup is overwriting my changes. Setting it in .gvimrc **does** work in MacVim. Between `:scriptnames` and `:verbose set guitablabel` it looks like just setting it in .vimrc should work, as it does in e.g. windows gvim.

See `:help setting-guitablabel` for more information and a more complicated function example; see `:help fname-modifiers` for more path-modifier options.

Comment: This solution sort of worked for me.  When I put this in my vimrc and sourced it, it set the tab names correctly.  But, as soon as I switched to another tab, all of the tabnames displayed `fnamemodify(bufname(` (the rest was truncated).  For some reason the code wasn't being evaluated and was inserted literally.  However, when I added an autocmd as per Conor's solution below `au BufEnter * set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}` it worked fine.  Thanks for the solution and alerting me to guitablabel.  Please update solution to reflect the comment and I'll check it as correct.

Comment: GUIEnter doesn't work for me. It works fine at first but once I write a buffer it stops working.

Comment: @pb2q second time you've swooped in behind me with a similar (but more thorough) answer for the win, hah. You deserve it man. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @SeanMackesey issue with the simple `set guitablabe=%!GuiTabLabel()` not working seems to be some complication of MacVim startup script order, or some issue with my config. Define the function in .vimrc **or** .gvimrc and add `set guitablabel=%!GuiTabLabel()` to .gvimrc, see if that works for you, and drop the `autocmd`

Comment: @pb2q Cool, it worked when I set it in gvimrc.  Unfortunate since I don't use this file for anything else, but hey it works!

Comment: FWIW, MacVim is overriding the `guitablabel` setting set in your `.vimrc` [here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/snapshot-142/src/MacVim/gvimrc#L34). I assume that file is loaded in between the loading of your `.vimrc` and your `.gvimrc`

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like

```
au BufEnter * set guitablabel=%{fnamemodify(bufname(winbufnr(1)), ":t")}
```

See `:help statusline` and `:help guitablabel` for more information. This basically sets the tab label to the name of the top-left window. There rest of this is in `:help`... `BufEnter`, `fnamemodify(`, `bufname(`, `winbufnr(`, etc.

Comment: watch out, `:.` can still get pretty long. For an exmaple, try loading a help file in the top-left buffer.

Comment: @Conner See my comment on pb2qs post for a solution that worked for me, it's a hybrid of yours and his.  Yours as written displays the full path, not just the filename.  Thanks for answer though.