# Show tab number in Macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I use Macvim as my development tool. Usually I switch between tabs.
But Macvim do not show tab number.
I config in my .vimrc for I can switch easily switch with cmd+1, cmd+2 or cmd+N.
But sometimes I need to count the tab number.
Is there a method can make Macvim show tab number like iTerm?

Answer (score 1):

Like GVIM, MacVim supports configuring the tab label via the `'guitablabel'` option. `:help setting-guitablabel` has an example to show tab page number and buffer name:

```
:set guitablabel=%N\ %f
```

There's also an example function to emulate the default behavior, you only need to work in the tab page number (which you can get via `tabpagenr()`), or customize to whatever you'd like.

Also see [Controlling Tab Names in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595301/controlling-tab-names-in-vim).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a partial answer in the documentation under `:help setting-guitablabel`:

```
:set guitablabel=%N\ %f
```

Where `%N\` is the tab number followed by a space.

If you want to keep the default setting and just prepend the tab number, you can use this:

```
:set guitablabel^=%N\ <--- note the space
```

To append the tab number:

```
:set guitablabel+=\ %N
```

---

As a side note, Vim's "tabline" looks and works like you would expect from your experience in other editors but "tab pages" are very different from your usual "tabs". It is generally recommended to get used to a buffer-centric workflow instead of relying on tab pages as file proxies (something they can't be by design).

Comment: Ha, almost the same answer :-) Does that `:set gtl^=...` really work? The default (in GVIM at least) is empty, and Vim then uses a special internal logic.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, nope, it didn't work in GVim on Debian.

Comment: Thanks for checking; that makes your answer slightly easier (but also a MacVim-only solution).

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful [plugin](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim) that works for all vims(gui and terminal). Just add

```
Plug 'mkitt/tabline.vim'  # if you're using vim-plug
```

to your .vimrc